# Solr - KeywordTokenizerFactory - No result with multiple terms

Tags: solr

I've got a strange behaviour on my Solr 8.8.2.

At indexation, I need to keep whole set of terms of one field, that's why I use the  KeywordTokenizerFactory.

Is is defined like this:

```
        <fieldType name="field1_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <field name="field1" type="field1_type" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
```

So this is a basic field that won't be tokenized and that will be set to lower case.

Now let's say I have a document with field1=value1 and another with field1=value2.

Here are the following request results by running a "q" query:

1. field1=(value1) => one result (ok)
2. field1=(value2) => one result (ok)
3. field1=(value1 value2) => no result (ko)
4. field1=(value1 OR value2) => 2 results (ok)

The third try shall have 2 results.

If I set the field1 to a raw solr.StrField type, the results are ok. It does no tokenization but this is not fitting my requirement to have fields in  lower case.

Furthermore, I've tested the demo (techproducts) provided by Solr by using the docker-solr and the KeywordTokenizerFactory is working as expected by querying using a similar field like "cat". The only difference was about the multiValued="true" that I added for further tests on my schema but no difference.

What parameter/configuration do you think I missed? I'm not aware of a parameter in my managed-schema or solrconfig that would impact this Tokenizer behaviour.

Just to let you know, every time I make a modification in the schema, I rebuild my whole docker (so data are ripped out).

All remarks or suggestions would be welcomed. Thank you by advance.

Comment: `q.op=OR`? Your default operator is set to `AND`, so when you don't specify any operator between your terms, it defaults to `AND`. When you specify `OR` explicitly, this doesn't happen. You can either change the default in your configuration or supply `q.op` in the request itself.

Comment: This is as simple as that! Thanks a lot for your accuracy!
In fact, I've checked this parameter on the slave node (which was in q.op=OR) and I did perform my tests on my slave (which has AND q.op by default).

Comment: So I've tested onto my slave which has q.op=OR now but I spoke too quickly, this is not working too. But I think I'm near the solution with your hint.

  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="q.op">OR</str>
       <str name="indent">false</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
     </lst>
 </requestHandler 

Even by adding the http parameter q.op=OR or by giving the syntax {!q.op=OR}(field1 field2). But sure there is something about OR not taken into account. I'll continue to search.

Comment: I had to combine q.op=OR with sow=true in order to have the correct behaviour. I'll run several tests to figure out the difference with the Solr demo.

Answer (score 0):

You have the default search operator set to `AND`. If you give `q.op=OR` as a parameter, the default operator will be `OR` instead, and you'll get the result you're looking for.

When you don't give a specific boolean operator between the two terms you're querying for, the default operator will be used. `field:(foo bar)` will then depend on the value of this operator. If you give `q.op=OR` you'll override this default setting and make sure that `foo` and `bar` are OR-ed together instead.